# Coordinating Java Threadpool with conditions

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a thread-pool that is getting stuck. The program below creates an instance of `ThreadLocks` and passes in a 1D array of integer values that act as "tasks".

The 1d Array represents the number of tasks needing to be done. (EX: `aValues = [100,200,300]`) is 100 tasks, 200 tasks and 300 tasks. Each `"Task layer"` in the previous index must be completed before the program moves to the proceeding index of tasks. So the 100 tasks in index 0 must be completed before the 200 tasks in index 1 is started.

My attempt to coordinate the tasks is done by using another `int` array of equal length to `aValues` (called `syncValues`). The program is designed to add 1 to the index in `syncvalues` when a task has been completed on that index. Therefore, when all the tasks in an `aValues` layer is complete, the index of `aValues` and `syncValues` should be the same and the program can continue.

This appears to work when the number of tasks are small, however **if the number of tasks are large** the program appears to **hang indefinitely**.

**How can I fix the code for a large number of tasks?**

I have stripped my code to make easier to understand.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Shows the number of tasks needing completion before moving to correct index.
        int values[] = {500,500,500};

        //The object to complete the tasks
        ThreadLocks obAnne = new ThreadLocks(values);

        //runs through the "tasks"
        obAnne.calculate();
    }
}

class ThreadLocks {

    /* Thread Lock for sync */
    public static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    /* ThreadPool that generates threads */
    private ExecutorService ThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    /* Nodes complete a set of tasks, add 1 to syncValues after task completion*/
    private Node[][] nodes;
    private int[] syncValues;

    /* The array that holds the "tasks" to be completed */
    private int aValues[];


    public ThreadLocks(int[] aValues)
    {
        this.aValues = aValues;
        this.syncValues = new int[aValues.length];
        this.nodes = createNewTopology(aValues);
    }


    /**
    * Create the nodes in a 2d array. these nodes hold the tasks to be created.
     */
    private Node[][] createNewTopology(int[] topology)
    {
        Node[][] tmpTopology = new Node[topology.length][];

        for (int layerX = 0; layerX < topology.length; layerX++)
        {   
            Node[] layer = new Node[topology[layerX]];
            syncValues[layerX] = 0;
            for (int layerY = 0; layerY < topology[layerX]; layerY++)
            {
                    layer[layerY] = new Node(layerX);
            }
            tmpTopology[layerX] = layer;
        }
        return tmpTopology;     
    }

    /* Process Inputs, produce outputs */
    public void calculate()
    {
        /* starts a time for dubug purposes */
        long Time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        /* starts at index 1 as index 0 are inputs */
        for(int layerX = 1; layerX < nodes.length; layerX++)
        {           
            for (int layerY = 0; layerY < nodes[layerX].length; layerY++)
            {
                ThreadPool.execute(nodes[layerX][layerY]);
            }

            while(syncValues[layerX] < aValues[layerX]) {}; 
        }
        /*tracks time taken.. its how i know its done */
        System.out.print("Current Time :" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - Time));
    }


    private class Node implements Runnable
    {
        /* sets the node layer. describes what index of aValues the node is in.*/
        private int layerX;

        public Node(int layerX) {
            this.layerX = layerX;
        }

        /* Processes Data for Node on separate thread */
        @Override
        public void run()
        {   
            /* TASK WOULD BE PUT HERE */

            lock.lock();
            try {syncValues[layerX]++;}
            catch (Exception e){System.out.print("LockError");}
            finally{lock.unlock();}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can surround your code using the back tick to indicate code fragments in your text (`\``). Triple back ticks you can use to indicate code blocks without having to re-indent. Please see my edit. Try and keep your questions as concise as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an AtomicInteger? it handles concurrency for you without you having to write synchronization code.

Comment: ...because I didn't think of it. And... IT WORKS! Wow. not only does this clean up some bulky code, my performance seems to have actually slightly increased! Thank you!

Comment: EDIT: Interesting. While this should in theory work, the results seem a bit off. Ive added a simple print statement at the end of the first for loop. It should print out a value equal to the aValues index but is off by 1 or 2 each time..

Comment: Hey Chris, could you do a threadPool.shutdown(); then threadPool.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS); after the for loop to wait for the threads to finish execution before printing the values?

Comment: It's not my intent to shut down the thread pool. As soon as the calculate method is finished I intend to immediately run it again. Efficiency is the primary concern and I worry the overhead of shutting down and starting a new threadpool for every calling of the method "calculate" will cost precious time.

Comment: I've finally got it working. It seems the issue was with the initialization of the AtomicIntegerArray. Thanks.